# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named sqlparse

Tags: python, django

When I try to run the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get an error stating that there is no module named `sqlparse`. I ran the commands

```
pip install sqlparse
conda install sqlparse
```

and it says that it's already installed but the error persists.

[image: Error screen shot]

[image: conda install screen shot]

Comment: You haven't activated your custom django conda environment when installing. You've installed it into the base environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple pythons installed on your system sqlparse is installed somewhere else but your application is using python from somewhere else. For example your app is using C:/Useres/oakej/AppData/../..  but actually sqlparse is installed somewhere else.
Please take note of both the paths carefully. It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using django in virtual environment, you might forgot to start pipenv shell

```sh
pipenv shell
python manager.py runserver
```

i just only started with django, and i got this error after closing and opening terminal
so i tried this and worked...